# Capital gains from bullion sales

Tags: tax-law

I read on the internet that one can sell, **online**, less than 25 troy ounces of  gold Maple Leaf coins without reporting the sale to the IRS. Is this true? Is this over a calendar year?

Answer (score 3):

[if you sell less then 25 1oz Maple Leaf gold coins, you do not have to file a 1099-B **at the time of the sale**](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/081616/understanding-taxes-physical-goldsilver-investments.asp). You still have to report the proceeds on Schedule D when you file your income taxes for the year.

Comment: So I still have to pay capital gains taxes. I just don't have to file a 1099-B immediately.

Comment: @catsteevens Correct.